# Create an API endpoint in ASP.NET Web API using C# to receive a post and store the data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Forgive me I'm a n novice at APIs. In ASP.NET Framework 4.7.2 Web API, I need to create an API endpoint to receive updates when an external event happens.

When the event happens the endpoint will receive the below JSON:

```
{
    "dispatch": 
        {
            "OrderID": "ABC123",
            "DispatchDate": "2020-11-20",
            "ConsignmentNo": "ABCV123456", 
            "TrackingUrl": "https://www.anyco.com?consignment=ABCV123456"
        }
}
```

For the above I have the following class

```
public class Tracking
{
    public string OrderID { get; set; }
    public DateTime DispatchDate { get; set; }
    public string ConsignmentNo { get; set; }
    public string TrackingUrl { get; set; }
}
```

I have the API get endpoints working from here:- https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/261/integrating-web-api-with-asp-net-razor-web-pages

I just need to get the `POST` part to read the JSON and then I can store the parts of it I want.

```
// POST api/<controller>
public void Post([FromBody]Tracking tracking) 
{
    // read jason
    // Save to db
}
```

The GET part of my API render the correct Jason with pre filled data.  I just don't know how to read the incoming Jason sent by the other party, pull out the 2 parts I want.

Any and all pointers would be welcome.

Comment: What does your Movie class looks like and what is the exact problem?

Comment: The Movie class can look like what ever we need to it to get it to work. I have added just the OrderID, DispatchDate, ConsignmentNo and TrackingUrl to it currently.

Comment: You are following the tutorial exacty, meaning that `movies.Add(movie);` means you are simply adding the object to a `List<Movie>` *in-memory*. Try printing the actual list or displaying it in some way...you will probably see the movie there

Comment: You are correct I will store it in a database. but I don t know how to pull out the bit I need to store in the correct place.  The List<Movie> just comes from the help guid iv used to set up the endpoint.

Comment: Ok so that is a very different problem then "my POST is not working" because otherwise I don't see an issue with the POST logic you have included. What database are you planning to use? What library are you going to connect with, ADO.NET, dapper, entity framework, etc?

Comment: Essentially, the table needs to be defined in the db, then you pass the object to a method that will use the data connector to run an INSERT sql command or stored procedure. Then you can take a look at the db to verify if it went properly. You can also now run SELECT command or stored procedure to read that data back and use it

Comment: I currently use ADO.NET to post to the db, i can wright this fine, i just need to know how to read the Jason that is sent to the endpoint. So i can pull out what i need and wright it tot he db

Comment: your json does not send `Movie` data you need to have a new Class `Order` with the expected properties!!

Comment: Hi Rui, Sorry the Movie thing has sent people off on a tangent here, I have re written that class into orders, I just need to know who to read the Jason that comes in so i can get the bit i want to wright to the db.

Comment: You have a typo error in `"https://www.anyco.com?consignment=ABCV123456”` the  `"` at the end is not correct. Should be `"` and it is `”`

Comment: Edit your question and show us what classes are you using, because if they are not correct, it will not work.

Comment: Assuming the value `dispatch` is always dispatch you need: 
public class Order
    {
        public string OrderID { get; set; }
        public string DispatchDate { get; set; }
        public string ConsignmentNo { get; set; }
        public string TrackingUrl { get; set; }
    }

    public class Dispatch
    {
        public Order dispatch { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Hi Rui, Thank you for your help, I have already made that class you can see it above now. If I use this class with the GET operation it renders the correct into, in the correct format. I just need to know how to work with the Jason that is send by the other side in the Post, so I can pull out what I need and store it in my db.

Comment: The example JSON you have does not match your class... so it will not work.... Do you have control over the json posted? Can you remove the `dispatch` so it will be: 
`{
            "OrderID": "ABC123",
            "DispatchDate": "2020-11-20",
            "ConsignmentNo": "ABCV123456", 
            "TrackingUrl": "https://www.anyco.com?consignment=ABCV123456"
        }`

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to sort this with help from a few people.

```
private List<Dispatch> dispatches = new List<Dispatch>();

// POST api/<controller>
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] DispatchData data)
{
    Dispatch dispatch = data.Dispatch;

    var tracking = dispatch.ConsignmentNo;

    // save to db code here

    return Json(dispatch);

}

public class DispatchData
{
    public Dispatch Dispatch { get; set; }
}

public class Dispatch
{
    public string OrderID { get; set; }
    public DateTime DispatchDate { get; set; }
    public string ConsignmentNo { get; set; }
    public string TrackingUrl { get; set; }
}
```